# What probability method do I use to solve this question

Tags: probability

Consider a fair deck of cards with 4 Suits

$$x \in \{ \spadesuit, \heartsuit, \clubsuit, \diamondsuit \}$$

Player 1 wins if we draw a $$\spadesuit $$
Player 2 wins if we draw any $$\heartsuit, \clubsuit, \diamondsuit $$

Pr(p1) = 1/4
Pr(p2) = 3/4

Given a series where a player wins if there card is drawn 4 times,  The cards are replaced after each draw, so each draw is independent.

The max amount of times we can draw cards is 7.
either p1 wins 4 times and p1 wins 3 times, or vice versa.

What is the probability the series goes for 7 draws?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that player 1 wins on draw $x$ is, the ways to draw 3 hearts and $x-4$ not-hearts before the fourth heart, times the probability of drawing each. $$P(X_1=x) = \frac{(x-1)!}{3!(x-4)!} \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^4 \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{x-4}$$
The probability that player 2 wins on draw $x$ is, similarly reasoned $$P(X_2=x) = \frac{(x-1)!}{3!(x-4)!} \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{x-4} \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{4}$$.
Thus the probability that *someone* wins on draw $x$ is the sum of these: $$P(X_1=x \cup X_2=x) = \frac{(x-1)!}{3!(x-4)!}\cdot\frac{3^4+3^{x-4}}{4^x}$$
Hence the probability that someone wins on draw 7 is: $$P(X_1=7 \cup X_2=7) = \frac{6!}{3!\;3!}\cdot\frac{3^4+3^{3}}{4^7} = \frac{135}{1024}$$

Comment: So a geometric probability distribution is what I believe this is?

Comment: @user127254 It's *based on* the **binomial distribution** (get $r$ successes before $n$ fails), but with the second competitor determining the number of fails allowed (get $r$ successes before the competitor's $r$ successes).